# Rails using javascript - By changing drop down values change its text_field values and it next auto calculate

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm stucking with one problem. I have one dropdown box named product. I want to by selecting product item it shuold change product price(hidden_field)
and Then by entering  product quantity(text_field) it shuold calculate totalPrice(text_field) of that product

Here is my view file looks like

```
<%= form_for @product_fills, url: product_fills_path , method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <%= f.collection_select(:product_id, @products,:id,:name , {include_blank: '-- Active Nozzle --'}, {class:'form-control', id: 'product_select' }) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'price' , id: 'prices'  %>         
        <%= f.text_field :quantity ,   class:'form-control', placeholder: 'Quantity', id: 'quantity' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <%= f.text_field :amount , required: true, autocomplete: 'off', class:'form-control', placeholder: 'Amount', id: 'total_price' %>
      </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

      var price =  <%= @price %>
// Change value by changing drop down vlaues
      $("#product_select option").filter(function() {
        if $(this).val(<% @products %>) == $("#prices").val(price){
            return $("#product_select").val()
          }
        }      
      $("#product_select").on("change", function() {
          $("#prices").val(price);
      });


// Calculation
    $('#quantity').on('keyup', function(e) {
      var quantity = $(this).val();
      $('#total_price').val((price * quantity).toFixed(2));
    });

  });

</script>
```

my controller looks like this

```
def new

   @products = Product.where(id: @product_ids, active: true )
   @products.each do |product|
      puts "Product_PRICE: #{product.product_price}"
      @price = product.product_price
    end

end
```

Here the calculation function is working fine (it taking one price value),
But I have so many values in product dropdown box I want by changing product item value it shuold calculate appropriate total product price.

Comment: Add custom class for product and price, and use class becasue ID only works for first element in jquery

Comment: No It's not working! I tried

Comment: @BharatMane What are trying to do with this line `$(this).val(<% @products %>) == $("#prices").val(price)` ?

Comment: why don't you add some data-attributes to the options select and get those values on changing the product without doing server requests for just price. something like `<%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(@products.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id, {'data-price'=>p.price}] }, selected_key = f.object.product_id) %>` and modify your js to work with just client data, updating the fields that you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed this issue by passing array values for both drop-down(product) and text_field(price) 
and by changing selected index of drop-down item value, price index value also changed by change function.

Here my jquery looks like

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var price =  <%= @price.compact! %>
        // Change values by changing drop down vlaues
            $(".product_select").on("change", function() {
              var id = this.selectedIndex - 1
              $(".prices").val(price[id]);
              var selectedPrice = price[id];
        // Calculation
                $('#quantity').on('keyup', function(e) {
                  var quantity = $(this).val();
                  $('#total_price').val((selectedPrice * quantity).toFixed(2));
                });
             });
          });

   </script>
```

and changed in controller

```
 def new
    @product_ids = []
    @price = []

    @products = Product.where(id: @product_ids, active: true )
    @products.each do |product|
      @price[product.id] = product.product_price
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo with your jQuery syntax,

1 => quantity field should be numeric type, still you need to parse this value as integer with `parseInt()`

2 => pice should also be parsed with `parseFloat()`

3=> Not sure with $("#product_select option").filter(function() {...}), it also contains some typo.

Change select tag as

```
   <%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(@products.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id, {'data-price'=>p.product_price}] }), :include_blank => '-- Active Nozzle --', class: 'form-control', id: 'product_select'%>
```

Script customisation

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

      //var price =  "<%= @price %>";
     // Change value by changing drop down vlaues
      //$("#product_select option").filter(function() {
        //if($(this).val(<% @products %>) == $("#prices").val(price)){
            //return $("#product_select").val()
          //}
        //}      
      $("#product_select").change(function() {
        var price  = $(this).data("price");
        $("#prices").val(price);
      });


    // Calculation
    $('#quantity').on('keyup', function(e) {
      var price = parseFloat($("#prices").val());
      var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
      $('#total_price').val((price * quantity).toFixed(2));
    });

  });

</script>
```

Please test it, it should work.